# Data is not showing after form submited using POST

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form using a POST method, upon enter a name and clicking search, it is supposed to display the information from the database, with the term you used.

index.php

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="Submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Search.php

```
    <?php
 if (!$_POST) {
    include('index.php');
    } else {
    ?>
<h1>Server name<br />Official ItemDB!</h1>
<br />
<?php

    $search = $_POST["search"];
        MySQL_connect("localhost", "pernix_items", "#");
        MySQL_select_db("pernix_items");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($search) . "%'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
  {
  ?>
  <table border="1">
<?
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['desc'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
?>  
</tr>
</table>
```

I added the mysql_error(); function to dertime where I was going wrong, to this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($search) . "%'" or die(mysql_error()));
```

and gives me this

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home1/pernix/public_html/tools/item-list/search.php on line 21

My line 21 of search.php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

So I added another or die print error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably means that the function (`mysql_query`) failed. From the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) - it returns 'FALSE' if there is an error.

Comment: Try using `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($search) . "%'") or die(mysql_error());` as you are not using `or die()` right here and your problem is something else which will be shown when the `die()` statement executes

Comment: No error prints , http://pernix-rsps.com/tools/item-list/search.php  , but the search term does not appear after the query @Kypros

Comment: Also `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));` remove that semicolon at the end so it is: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){`

Comment: You are welcome but do make the switch to `mysqli` or `pdo` as soon as possible since you are using `mysql` which is being deprecated and very vulnerable for use in your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although resolved in the comments, reposting it here as a whole answer.

First the `or die()` line is wrong, as the die statement is executed **inside** the `mysql_query` and not as supposed to when and if the query fails, as it should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($search) . "%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Secondly you have an extra semicolon right after the `while()` line making, which should be removed to look like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{}
```

Last and most importantly you should really convert this code to `mysqli` or `pdo` as the `mysql` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.